# How to navigate with named routes from googleSignIn future method?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-signin

I have the googleSignIn method in a class AuthService in a separate file called auth.dart.

```dart
// in AuthService class
/.../
Future<FirebaseUser> googleSignIn() async {
    loading.add(true);

    GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
    GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth = await googleUser.authentication;
    final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
      accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
      idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
    );
    final FirebaseUser user = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
    updateUserData(user);
    print("signed in " + user.displayName);

    loading.add(false);
    return user;
  }
/.../
```

In the log in page (LogInPage.dart), I have a google sign in button.

```dart
// in _LogInPageState class
/.../
socialIcons(
  colors: [Color(0xffcb2d3e), Color(0xffef473a)],
  icon: Icon(
    FontAwesomeIcons.google,
    color: Colors.white,
  ),
  onPressed: () {
    final login = authService.googleSignIn();
    login.then(/*navigate to home page using named routes*/);
  },
),
/.../
```

I am trying to perform the code below after the googleSignIn() is completed in the onPressed.

```dart
Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
  '/home', (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
```

How do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your `googleSignIn` returns future.
You can simply use `then` and navigate to your desired widget.

```
    googleSignIn().then((FirebaseUser user) {
      //Navigation code here
    }).catchError((e) {
      //Error if any
    });
```